# Gulpfile not compiling Scss & JS properly

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I am trying to create a `gulpfile.js` to compile scss to css and JS components to a main JS file. But it's not working properly.
**The issues i am facing, when I run the command `gulp`:**

> 1. It doesn't compile JS components to a main JS file.
> 2. It compiles SCSS but when i save any file, the git-bash terminal executing files infinitely, here is the screenshot:
>     [image]

**Here is my gulpfile.js:**

```
"use strict";

const source = 'assets/';

// Load Modules
const { src, dest, watch, series } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const terser = require('gulp-terser');
const browsersync = require('browser-sync').create();

// Scss Task
function scssTask() {
    return src(`${source}/scss/zaincss.scss`)
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(postcss([cssnano()]))
    .pipe(dest(`${source}/css`));
}

// Javascript Task
function jsTask() {
    return src(`${source}/js/scripts/*.js`)
    .pipe(terser())
    .pipe(dest(`${source}/js/scripts/`));
}

// BrowserSync Tasks
function browserSyncServe(done) {
    browsersync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: '.'
        },
        injectChanges: true
    });
    done()
}

function browserSyncReload(done) {
    browsersync.reload();
    done();
}

// Watch Task
function watchTask() {
    watch('*.html', browserSyncReload);
    watch(['assets/scss/**/*.scss', 'assets/js/**/*.js'], series(scssTask, jsTask, browserSyncReload));
}

// Default Gulp Task
exports.default = series(
    scssTask, jsTask, browserSyncServe, watchTask
);
```

I have googled a lot, but i am stuck. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is you are watching the same directory that you are storing your `js` files in:

```js
// Javascript Task
function jsTask() {
    return src(`${source}/js/scripts/*.js`)
    .pipe(terser())
    .pipe(dest(`${source}/js/scripts/`));
}
```

So you send the files to `${source}/js/scripts/` but you are watching that location in your `watch` task: `'assets/js/**/*.js'`.  So any change in that location starts the process all over again.

Store you minified js files someplace else than the same directory you are watching for changes.

Comment: Now, I understand. I don't need to store somewhere else, I just need to change `.pipe(dest(`${source}/js/scripts/`))` to `.pipe(dest(`${source}/js/`))` and then in the watch task `['assets/scss/**/*.scss', 'assets/js/**/*.js']` to `['assets/scss/**/*.scss', 'assets/js/scripts/*.js']`.